# Create an s3 signature using xdmp:hmac-sha256() api in xquery

Tags: amazon-s3, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

How to create an s3 signature using `xdmp:hmac-sha256()` API in xquery?

I need to create this signature and use it in `xdmp:http-delete()` API to delete a file in S3. Suggest me any approach to do this from my xquery. All I need is to delete the file in s3 via my xquery.